# How to create a shortcut key for a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jlabel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74SmA.jpg)

I have a list `JLabel`. I want when click a label content display in `JTextArea` the same. Why when I click the label, the text area does not display?

#### The code:

```
   jLabel0.setText(namelist.get(0));
   jLabel1.setText(namelist.get(1));
   jLabel2.setText(namelist.get(2));
   jLabel3.setText(namelist.get(3));
   jLabel4.setText(namelist.get(4));
   jLabel5.setText(namelist.get(5));
    //String  b[]={"jLabel4","jLabel5","jLabel7","jLabel8","jLabel9","jLabel10"};
   for (int i=0;i<k;i++){
    
   String f=String.valueOf(i);
   JLabel jlb = new JLabel("jLabel"+f);
   String Af=file_list.get(i);
   FileReader F=new FileReader(Af);
   jlb.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
         }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if(e.getClickCount()==1)
            {
               
                try {
                    jTextArea3.read(F,"");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FAKENEWS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
           
        }
    });
   }
```

Comment: So, you seem to have gone a long way out of way your way to avoid simply using `JButton`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve it using `JButton` and just by making the button look like a label.
You will want to do the following once you have created the button:

```
     setFocusPainted(false);
     setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
     setContentAreaFilled(false);
     setBorderPainted(false);
     setOpaque(false);
```

You may want to exclude `setFocusPainted(false)` if you want it to actually paint the focus (e.g. dotted line border on Windows look and feel).

And after that you may use the button event handlers to do your desired action.

Comment: Ok Nivin John. I'll chek with JButton